# PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Tags: php, pdo

I have this error:

> PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\AppDarbNajah\App\Database.php on line 63

ArticleController code:

```
public function edit() {
        $id = $_GET['ID'];
        if(!empty($_POST) && (!empty($_FILES))){

           $this->Article->update($id, [
                 'ref' => $_POST['ref'],
                 'desig' => $_POST['desig'],
                 'category_id' => $_POST['category_id'],
                 'tva' => $_POST['tva'],
                 'unit_id' => $_POST['unit_id'],
                 'Supplier_id' => $_POST['box-infos-id'],
                 'thumb' => $_FILES['thumb']['name'],
                 'created_by' => 2855,
                 'updated_by' => 2855
              ]);
        }
        $categories = $this->Category->extract('ID', 'category');
        $units = $this->Unit->extract('ID', 'unit');
        $tva = $this->Tva->extract('ID', 'tva (%)');
        $article = $this->Article->find($id);
        var_dump($article);
        $form = new BootstrapForm($article);
        $this->render('articles/edit',compact('form', 'categories', 'units', 'tva'));
     }
```

Line 63 is:

```
'ref' => $_POST['ref']
```

I didn't write all code I wrote only the function that has error

update function code:

```
public function update($id, $fields){
     $sql_pairs = [];
     $attributes = [];
     foreach ($fields as $k =>$v){
        $sql_pairs[] = "$k = ?";
        $attributes[] = $v;
     }
     $attributes = [];
     $sql_parts = implode(', ', $sql_pairs);
     $this->query("UPDATE INTO {$this->table} SET $sql_parts WHERE ID = ?", $attributes);
  }
```

Comment: `PDOStatement::execute()` expects parameter 1 to be array, but your code apparently provided a string instead.

Comment: Which framework you are using?

Comment: Which line in your code sample is line 63 as referenced in the error?

Comment: Add line 63 (and related lines) to the question please.

Comment: line 63 is 'ref' => $_POST['ref'],  i didn't write all code i wrote only the function that has error

Comment: Can you provide the update() function  code ?

Comment: i added now @MalekZarkouna

Comment: I suggest to use the array() function ,It may  fix your problem

Comment: just remove `$attributes = [];` line before `$sql_parts = implode(', ', $sql_pairs);`

Answer (score 0):

the problem was i should use array [$id] in find function as the following:

```
public function find($id){
     return $this->query("SELECT * FROM {$this->table} WHERE ID = ?", [$id], true); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about library you use to create your model but your function is weird.

```
public function update($id, $fields){
     $sql_pairs = [];
     $attributes = [];
     // this bring an idea that you create list of fields to update  #ref1
     foreach ($fields as $k =>$v){
        $sql_pairs[] = "$k = ?";
        // here you add new value for next field to attributes #ref2
        $attributes[] = $v;
     }
     // here you reset all values collected (#ref2) #ref3
     // $attributes = []; //so let remove it
     // but instead we need to add ID value to our query
     $attributes[] = $id;
     $sql_parts = implode(', ', $sql_pairs);
     // UPDATE for MySQL should be something like :
     // UPDATE my_table SET col1="newval1", col2="newval2" WHERE ID = 1
     // lets try to get that format 

     $this->query("UPDATE {$this->table} SET $sql_parts WHERE ID = ?", $attributes);
  }
```

Hope now it will work better....